# R changes type of colnames from Date to numeric while assigning new colnames

Tags: r, date

I would like to keep colnames in date format, but R changes it automatically into numeric and after that into character string.

Example:

```
db <- data.frame()
db <- rep(1:3, times=20)
db <- t(db)
colnames(db) <- c(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), length.out = 60, by= 'days'))
```

> class(colnames(db))
>   [1] "character"
>
> colnames(db)
>    [1] "15706" "15707" "15708" "15709" "15710" "15711" "15712" "15713" "15714" "15715" "15716" "15717" "15718"
>   [14] "15719" "15720" "15721" "15722" "15723" "15724" "15725" "15726" "15727" "15728" "15729" "15730" "15731"
>   [27] "15732" "15733" "15734" "15735" "15736" "15737" "15738" "15739" "15740" "15741" "15742" "15743" "15744"
>   [40] "15745" "15746" "15747" "15748" "15749" "15750" "15751" "15752" "15753" "15754" "15755" "15756" "15757"
>   [53] "15758" "15759" "15760" "15761" "15762" "15763" "15764" "15765"
>
> class(c(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), length.out = 60, by= 'days')))
>   [1] "Date"
>
> c(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), length.out = 60, by= 'days'))
>    [1] "2013-01-01" "2013-01-02" "2013-01-03" "2013-01-04" "2013-01-05" "2013-01-06" "2013-01-07" "2013-01-08"
>    [9] "2013-01-09" "2013-01-10" "2013-01-11" "2013-01-12" "2013-01-13" "2013-01-14" "2013-01-15" "2013-01-16"
>   [17] "2013-01-17" "2013-01-18" "2013-01-19" "2013-01-20" "2013-01-21" "2013-01-22" "2013-01-23" "2013-01-24"
>   [25] "2013-01-25" "2013-01-26" "2013-01-27" "2013-01-28" "2013-01-29" "2013-01-30" "2013-01-31" "2013-02-01"
>   [33] "2013-02-02" "2013-02-03" "2013-02-04" "2013-02-05" "2013-02-06" "2013-02-07" "2013-02-08" "2013-02-09"
>   [41] "2013-02-10" "2013-02-11" "2013-02-12" "2013-02-13" "2013-02-14" "2013-02-15" "2013-02-16" "2013-02-17"
>   [49] "2013-02-18" "2013-02-19" "2013-02-20" "2013-02-21" "2013-02-22" "2013-02-23" "2013-02-24" "2013-02-25"
>   [57] "2013-02-26" "2013-02-27" "2013-02-28" "2013-03-01"

How can I keep colnames formated as date and why is R changing date type automatically?

Comment: convert to character, i.e. `colnames(db) <- as.character(c(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), length.out = 60, by= 'days')))`

Comment: Thanks @Sotos, it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sotos comment is a solution:

```
colnames(db) <- as.character(c(seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), length.out = 60, by= 'days')))
```